# How to apply PostgreSQL UNLOGGED feature to an existing table?

Tags: postgresql

Can I ALTER an existing table to be UNLOGGED?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

PostgreSQL 9.5+ allows setting an existing table as **LOGGED** / **UNLOGGED** with the [ALTER TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-altertable.html) command... detailed better [here](http://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-5-feature-highlight-alter-table-unlogged/).

```
For e.g. 
ALTER TABLE table_test SET LOGGED;
ALTER TABLE table_test SET UNLOGGED;
```

Answer (score 15):

The following solution is for PostgreSQL versions<=9.4:

You can do:

```
create unlogged table your_table_alt as 
   select * from your_table;
```

Then:

```
drop table your_table;
alter table your_table_alt rename to your_table;
```

Comment: Also, remember you can wrap those commands in a transaction so no one ever sees the intermediary bits and pieces.

Comment: Before dropping the old table, please check and recreate indexes and constraints on the new table.