# Postgres: alter table to unlogged

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have seen this answer, [How to apply PostgreSQL UNLOGGED feature to an existing table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938610/how-to-apply-postgresql-9-1-unlogged-feature-to-an-existing-table/7938621#7938621), which basically suggests that the way to convert a table to unlogged is to run:

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE your_table_unlogged AS SELECT * FROM your_table;
```

Is this still the case, because while this is an of obvious working solution, for a large table there are potential time and disk space factors that could come into play. And, if yes, could someone please explain briefly how the architecture of Postgres means you need to rewrite an entire table in order to make it unlogged?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply PostgreSQL 9.1 UNLOGGED feature to an existing table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938610/how-to-apply-postgresql-9-1-unlogged-feature-to-an-existing-table)

Comment: @gbjbaanb, I mentioned that post and asked a couple of additional questions based on it.

Comment: Not a duplicate at all. Interesting question, really.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Update*: In PostgreSQL 9.5+ there is `ALTER TABLE ... SET LOGGED` and `... SET UNLOGGED`

Converting from `UNLOGGED` to `LOGGED` requires that the whole table's data be written to xlogs if `wal_level` is > `minimal` so replicas get a copy. So it's not free, but it can still be worth creating a table unlogged, populating it then setting it logged if you have a bunch of cleanup and deletion and merging work to do on the table after initial load.

---

Yes, that's still the case in 9.4.

Converting from logged to `UNLOGGED` isn't theoretically hard AFAIK, but nobody's done the work to do it. The main thing is that all constraints and types etc referring to it must be re-checked to make sure there's no reference from another logged table to this table. Most attention has been paid to the other case, so if this feature is important to you, consider funding its development or getting involved in development yourself.

Converting `UNLOGGED` to logged may become possible for nodes that aren't involved in streaming replication or using an `archive_command`. It's not simple otherwise because of the need to cope with the fact that the data for the table wasn't sent, but suddenly changes to it are - the replication protocol would need further enhancement to allow the table to be base-copied before continuing.

Comment: thanks, yes, I see why changing something mid-stream would be problematic, I was more thinking about a one off "offline" change. If it is just, and I use the word with caution, checking for references in other tables, the total table rewrite approach above seems like overkill.

Comment: As far as getting involved with Postgres development is concerned, I would love to, but lack the C skills, let alone database internal knowledge to do so. I have been pushing my boss to make contributions to a couple of OS projects for a while -- colleagues spending hours installing expensive prop software helps -- maybe some time in the future.

Comment: Trouble is that with pitr and wal archiving there is no "offline". Wouldn't prevent logged to unlogged conversion but it makes the other way much harder, and unlogged to logged is the main area people have been interested in. As for C dev: learn by doing. I knew none, but i found things I wanted to improve - so I learned.

Comment: 9.5 has set unlogged and set logged. For some reason, setting unlogged takes a long time for a large table. Is it force-committing it all to disk before it goes unlogged?

Comment: @sudo Correct, `SET LOGGED` must (if `wal_level` is > `minimal`) write the whole table to the transaction logs before setting it logged, so replicas have a copy of it.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently this (alter table ... set logged | unlogged) has been implemented in (the upcoming) postgresql 9.5.

Comment: Page of GSoC project of "set logged" - https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Allow_an_unlogged_table_to_be_changed_to_logged_GSoC_2014 ("Allow an unlogged table to be changed to logged GSoC 2014") Next year project by Fabriziomello was to improve conversion operation performance - https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Improve_the_performance_of_ALTER_TABLE_SET_LOGGED_UNLOGGED_statement ("Improve the performance of ALTER TABLE SET LOGGED UNLOGGED statement")