# Can hibernate autogenerate an unlogged table?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
}

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Is it possible that hibernate will generate a `CREATE unlogged TABLE` statement instead of `CREATE TABLE` when the table for `MyEntity` does not exist?

Comment: what do you mean by CREATE unlogged TABLE????

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html Data written to unlogged tables is not written to the write-ahead log (see Chapter 29), which makes them considerably faster than ordinary tables.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938610/how-to-apply-postgresql-9-1-unlogged-feature-to-an-existing-table

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by subclassing the relevant Postgres dialect and overriding the `getCreateTableString()` method as below.

```
public class CustomPostgresSQLDialect extends PostgresSQLxxDialect{

    @Override
    public String getCreateTableString() {
        return "create unlogged table";
    }   
}
```

And obviously set this as your dialect:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.foo.CustomPostgresSQLDialect "/>
```

Comment: That's a great idea. Anyhow that would force all of my tables to be an unlogged table? (I only want to define one specific). Or can I tie the dialect to an entity explicit?

Comment: I do not see any easy way. If you look the source of org.hibernate.mapping.Table.sqlCreateString(..) you have info about the table/mapping at this point but obviously it is not passed to the method above.

Comment: Another option may be to override org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration/AnnotationConfiguration and post-process the relevant String returned by generateSchemaCreationScript(...) or generateSchemeUpdateScript(...)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no param in `@Entity` or `@Table` to pass that kind of options to the DBMS. Found [this feature request](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8050) in hibernate's jira though, it covers your use case, maybe you want to vote for it.

Anyway you can try and add an [auxiliary database object](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-database-object) in the hibernate configuration to run `ALTER TABLE MyEntity SET UNLOGGED`, it's the easiest way i can think of doing that DDL modification.

Answer (score 0):

You should use update rather than create

this is helpful:

[Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633263/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-default-value)

Comment: So what do you mean by unlogged table. Hbm2dll auto update will create those table for you which does not exist in schema

Comment: Data written to unlogged tables is not written to the write-ahead log (see Chapter 29), which makes them considerably faster than ordinary tables. 
 
postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html

Comment: It is not possible to do it from hibernate. You have to set it through alter sql query on your database